# Are there any intersections between Theory A and Theory B?

Tags: terminology, ho.history-overview, research-practice

In the following two questions [Origins and applications of Theory A vs Theory B?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1521/53307) and [Solid applications of category theory in TCS?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/944/solid-applications-of-category-theory-in-tcs), many people shared their knowledge and opinions about the division of those two areas in theoretical CS.

I am a student in mathematics with experience in both graph theory and category theory, crucial mathematical knowledge for theory A and B, respectively, and I am seeking to learn more and probably even do some serious research in theoretical CS. I am interested in whether there are any intersections between theory A and B, and if so, are there any people who have done some work in the intersections or at least are there any references in this topic?

Comment: Can we (as a community) just stop using these completely unhelpful terms, please?

Comment: Despite giving an answer, I also think the labels are not very well defined, have more sociological than scientific meaning, and are not all that helpful.

Comment: In the first question you link, automata are described as Theory A. I would say they were mainly Theory A in the 70's or 80's (studied as a weak model of computation), but they are now much more a Theory B subject. Or at least, they are both and can count as a natural intersection.

Comment: @DavidRicherby How about Theory A and Theory $\alpha$?

Answer (score 7):

One cool example of work that straddles things that are typically considered theory A and things typically considered theory B are the lower bounds on the running time of the simplex algorithm with randomized pivoting rules, due to [Friedmann, Hansen, and Zwick](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~abasu9/RFG/pivotexponential.pdf). The lower bounds rely on lower bounds for policy iteration algorithms for parity games, which are a tool used in formal verification and automata theory.

Answer (score 6):

One example (from my research field) is analysis of dynamical systems: in a (linear) dynamical system, you are given a matrix $A\in {\mathbb Q}^{d\times d}$ and you reason about various properties of $A^n$. For example, the *Kannan-Lipton Orbit Problem* asks, given two vectors $s,t\in \mathbb Q^d$, whether there exists $n$ such that $A^ns=t$.

These types of problems can be looked at as reachability problems for linear loops, which places them well in the domain of formal verification, SIG-LOG, and Theory B.

However, the technical analysis typically uses tools from number theory, analysis, and algebraic computations, which are more in the scope of Theory A.

A good place to start reading on these is [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2857050).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, linear logic and "implicit complexity theory" use tools that are often found in Theory B (type theory, theory of programming languages, etc.) to capture and study complexity classes. Some of this work goes back to [Bellantoni & Cook](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01201998). More recently, the work of [Ugo Dal Lago](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~dallago/research.html) comes to mind.

Comment: Though perhaps someone more knowledgable in the area could add more references, like @AndrejBauer?

Comment: Or @NeelKrishnaswami?